# Laravel: find posts from current user

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I´ve cloned this sample app: https://github.com/codekerala/laravel-and-vue.js-spa-Recipe-Box

In RecipeController there's an index function that returns all posts (or recipes in this case). I need to get only recipes added by the current logged in user.

```
public function index()
  {
      $currentuser = Auth::id();
      $recipes = Recipe::where('user_id', '=', $currentuser)
                 ->get(['id', 'name', 'image']);

      return response()
        ->json([
          'recipes' => $recipes
        ]);
  }
```

When trying this, my `recipes` array is empty, but no other errors from what I can see. I can hardcode value `1` instead of `$currentuser` and it returns all recipes that are made by user # 1.

I am declaring `use Auth;`, but am new to the Laravel framework, maybe someone could give any assistance?

Using Laravel 5.4.15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be any problem in `Auth::user()` please check it.
Add the following in your controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

And add a constructor

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function index()
  {
      $currentuser = Auth::user();
      dump($currentuser);
      $recipes = Recipe::where('user_id', '=', $currentuser->id)
                 ->get(['id', 'name', 'image']);

      return response()
        ->json([
          'recipes' => $recipes
        ]);
  }
```

Comment: This returns error: `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: check whether it returns a user or not

Comment: dump of $currentuser returns null

Comment: Did you check your Auth?

Comment: $currentuser = Auth::user();
dump($currentuser);

returns null

Comment: Ah, there was already a constructor:
$this->middleware('auth:api')->except(['index','show']); 

I removed 'index' from the except array, and it worked.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: @AnkushSood You had identified the problem, then why don't you try to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem in your current user. You are not able to retrieve user id
Just use this statement.

$current_user = \Auth::user()->id;